# Printing contents of sets included in a map

Tags: c++, maps, set

I am writing a program that reads team names from a file and divides them into groups. Each group of size 4. I am using a:

```
map<int, set<string> > groups
```

Assume the team names to be countries names.
Now after entering all the team names into the resp. groups I want to print the contents of each group and this is where I am getting stuck.

Here is the full working code, I have written so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
void form_groups(vector<string>);
int main(){
        srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
        string team_name;
        vector<string> teams;
        while (cin >> team_name)
        {
                teams.push_back(team_name);
        }
        random_shuffle(teams.begin(), teams.end());
        form_groups(teams);
}
void form_groups(vector<string> teams)
{
        map<int, set<string> > groups;
        map<int, set<string> >::iterator it;
        string curr_item;
        int curr_group = 1;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++)
        {
                curr_item = teams.at(i);
                count++;
                if(count == 4)
                {
                        curr_group += 1;
                        count = 0;
                }
                groups[curr_group].insert(curr_item);
        }
        cout << curr_group << endl;
        for(it = groups.begin(); it != groups.end(); ++it)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it the last `for` loop, the iteration over the `groups` `map` you are unsure of?

Comment: Yes.I want to print the contents in that and I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine. By using `map<int, set<string> >::iterator it` you can access a the given `<key,value>` pair with `it->first` and `it->second`. Since `set<string>` is a standard container itself you can use an `set<string>::iterator` to traverse through the elements:

```
map<int, set<string> >::iterator map_it;
set<string>::iterator set_it

for(map_it = groups.begin(); map_it != groups.end(); ++map_it){
    cout << "Group " << it->first << ": ";

    for(set_it = map_it->second.begin(); set_it != map_it->second.end(); ++set_it)
         cout << *set_it << " ";

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While iterating over a `std::map<..>`, `it->first` would give you the key, and `it->second` would give you the corresponding value.

You would need something like this to iterate over the map:

```
for(it = groups.begin(); it != groups.end(); ++it)
{
    cout<<"For group: "<<it->first<<": {"; //it->first gives you the key of the map.

    //it->second is the value -- the set. Iterate over it.
    for (set<string>::iterator it2=it->second.begin(); it2!=it->second.end(); it2++)
        cout<<*it2<<endl;
    cout<<"}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it is the iteration over the `groups` `map` that is your difficulty. Example of iterating over a `map`:

```
for (it = groups.begin(); it != groups.end(); it++)
{
    // 'it->first' is the 'int' of the map entry (the key)
    //
    cout << "Group " << it->first << "\n";

    // 'it->second' is the 'set<string>' of the map entry (the value)
    //
    for (set<string>::iterator name_it = it->second.begin();
         name_it != it->second.end();
         name_it++)
    {
        cout << "  " << *name_it << "\n";
    }
}
```