# How to print out a map with different types

Tags: c++, dictionary, cout

I have a next map:

```
map<string, set<int>> myMap;
```

How can I print its values out?

I've tried to do it in two ways "auto" and iterators also, but it gives me the next error:

> invalid operands to binary expression

---

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x;
  int g = 0;
  vector<string> words;
  map<int, int> documents_to_relevance;
  map<string, set<int>> word_to_documents;
  cin >> x;
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    words.push_back(word);
  }
  for(auto word_to_cout : words)
  {
    word_to_documents[word_to_cout].insert(g);
    g++;
  }
  map<string, set<int>>::iterator it = word_to_documents.begin();
  cout << "Words in map with id:";
  for(map<string, set<int>>::const_iterator it = word_to_documents.begin(); it != word_to_documents.cend(); it++)
  {
    cout << "Id for " << it->first << "is " << it->second << endl; 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? Without code we can only guess.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/J5py3Rzz I hope links is allowed here.

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: @АнтонАнаньев : it is always better to write the code inside the question itself  (I have just done it for you). The only exception is when you only give a minimal example inside the question, and put the full code in a link as reference

Comment: I think that the answer to your question are in [that other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11381586/3545273). Please say if it is not enough for you, and why. BTW, credits should remain to @youcantseeme for idenfying the duplicate.